# What is exactly being declared by typedef?

Tags: c, typedef

```
typedef struct nodetype node;
typedef node *link;

struct nodetype
{
 int  dat;
 link ptr;
};


typedef link *stack;
```

In the code above I am a little confused on what is all being defined.
I understand what `typedef` does, but I am still wondering what exactly is being defined by `typedef  node *link;` Is it defining a pointer to a node? Also I have the same question for the `typedef link *stack;`

Comment: "Is it creating a pointer to a node or is it creating a structure pointer to a node" - what's this "structure pointer" concept you have, and how does it differ from a regular pointer? Usually, when people say "structure pointer", they just mean a pointer where the pointed-to type is a struct type, so the only difference between "pointer to a node" and "structure pointer to a node" is a bit of terminological redundancy.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really understand `typedef`. That gives a new name to an existing type, and the syntax is just the same as declaring a variable; except that adding in the key word `typedef` means that the identifier is an alias for the type, instead of a variable of that type.

Comment: I asked the question wrong. I guess I should have put more time into thinking what to ask and that is my bad. I do however understand what is happening now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` lines are not creating anything. `typedef` is used to give new names for types, they are not declarations or definitions of variables, so nothing is really creating at this moment.

```
typedef node *link;
```

means `link` is another name for the type `node *`. Only when you use it like:

```
link link_varialbe;
```

A variable of type `link` (the same as `node *`) is created.

Comment: They are creating new types, if you regard defining as creating.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin no they aren't. `node *` and `link` are exactly the same type .

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: No, `typedef` merely creates a new name for an existing type.

Comment: @MattMcNabb They are separate definitions. I'm not sure which part got confusing. `typedef` defines new types, and if you regard defining as creating, you could say that `typedef` creates new types. `link` does not exist without that line, does it?

Comment: I meant defining so that was my bad.

Comment: @Tho You are quite wrong here. Again, `typedef` declares aliases and does not define or create new types.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: "A **`typedef`** declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym for the type so specified." That's a quote from the ISO C standard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Say you have a friend called Bob. At some point you've decided to call him Taco. That name came out of nowhere, didn't it? And you're the author of it. You created that name right there. Shall we get philosophical about this? Or maybe we shall dive into theology and say God *created* everything and we're merely playing with them, huh?

Comment: @Tho You can't really argue with Keith's standard quote surely

Comment: You've created a new name. You haven't created a person. There is no new person, just as there's no new type.

Comment: I wonder if you people regard declaring a variable as *creating*, since, you know, it's just an alias to the object in memory which existed all along. Then I also wonder if you regard *anything* as *creating*.

Comment: @David Why? You all are arguing against my *"It didn't exist before, did it?"* argument, which should alone be a solid proof that something has been created one way or another.

Comment: @Tho You cannot argue against the standard since it defines the language. We all agree that `typedef` declares something. It's just what it declares. You claim it declares a new type. The standard says otherwise.

Comment: @David It doesn't define the English language, and [creating](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?word=Create) is undeniably one of the things that `typedef` does.

Comment: @Tho `typedef` doesn't create types

Comment: @David Say it 10 more times an maybe it'll happen. Yeah, to be precise, `typedef` doesn't create types, it defines types and it created that `link` over there.

Comment: @Tho it defines synonyms for types, as described in the standard

Comment: @Tho "... if you people regard declaring a variable as creating, since, you know, it's just an alias to the object in memory which existed all along." That's simply not the case. A variable declaration is (in most cases) also a variable *definition*, which is in fact precisely the statement that causes memory to be reserved for the object--i.e., it creates the object in memory.

Comment: In any case, this whole argument seems to be about whether an alias for a type is itself considered a "type" or not, rather than about whether what's happening here can be considered "creation" in the general sense. Yes, the `typedef` statement creates something, but that something is an alias for an existing type rather than a new type. Happy now?

Comment: @Kyle I guess that's it. I was considering, as you said, for example, `int` as a type. I was doing that as an everyday convention. For example, I could say "You are *Kyle*", but that'd be wrong. Instead "Your name is *Kyle*" would be right, and you are... *(Kyle)*? Yeah... And there is no type `int`; `int` is just a name for the type `(int)`. `typedef` creates things like `int` and `char` which are names.

Comment: @Tho I hate to be so contrary, but `int` and `char` really _are_ "types": that is to say, the words themselves refer to the information the compiler has about how much memory is required by objects of each *type* and how various operations/operators (`*`, `+`, etc) on each type work. This is the definition of a type. (The standard's definition is "the meaning of a value stored in an object or returned by a function.")

Comment: `link`, however, is _not_ a type, since it does not refer directly to the "meaning" of an expression of type `link`; instead, it's merely an *alias* for the *type* `node*` (assuming that `node` is itself a type rather than another `typedef` alias). Ultimately, such an alias is "expanded" by the compiler into its "real" type, which is a `struct`, a primitive type (e.g. `int`), a `union`, or a pointer to one of the other three types.

Comment: So, to return to your person-name analogy, you might consider my "type" to be `homo sapien`, but we've assigned the shorthand words "person", "human", etc. to that type; the situation is analogous to defining a `struct` called `homo_sapien`, then declaring `typedef homo_sapien human`.

Answer (score 1):

`node` is an alias for the type `struct nodetype`; `link` is an alias for the type `node *`, meaning it's also an alias for the type `struct nodetype *`.

`stack` is an *object* of type `link *`, which is the same as type `node **`, which is the same as type `struct nodetype **`.

This is a *horrible* example of how to use typedefs, precisely because of the confusion it is causing you.  It's creating a bunch of different names for the same thing with no good reason, *and* it's hiding a pointer in one of typedef names which is almost always bad juju.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` defines an alias for a given type.
Its merit is to give some special meaning to the elements of your code.